# How can I change the value of multiselect programmatically angular

Tags: angularjs, multi-select

I have a multiselect:

```
<select id="statuses-multi" ng-multiselect multiple="" ng-model="search.lastStatuses"
                                        ng-options="status for status in ctrl.statuses track by status">
</select>
```

And the directive ng-multiselect:

```
app.directive('ngMultiselect', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: false,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue) {
            scope.$evalAsync(function() {
               $(element).dropdown();
            });
        });

    }
}
});
```

Everything works fine as long as a user chooses everything by hand. However, I need to have some values already preselected.
I tried to use simple `search.lastStatuses.push(some_value)` - doesn't work. 
It just shows that it has this some_value object but doesn't show that. Moreover, after the first selection of the user it gets erased.

Comment: What's $(..).dropdown() ? Which library is it ? You should make a plunkr to get fast assistance. Coz now you're making it hard for us to reproduce the issue and be able to test our answers as we have no idea what .dropdown() is .

Answer (score 0):

When watching an array, you should use

```
scope.$watchCollection(attrs.ngModel, function(newValue) { /*...*/ });
```

instead of just a $watch, in order to update the view when items get's pushed in the array.

Answer (score -1):

When you use ng-options, the model will have an array of complete object. If you try to put just values in the model array, it will not work. Try iterating over the list ctrl.statuses and push the complete object in search.lastStatuses which you want pre-selected.

Hope that helps. Happy programming!

Comment: Check: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2566-scope-watch-vs-watchcollection-in-angularjs.htm and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope